# taylor series and uniform convergence

Tags: real-analysis

Maybe is a silly question but I am confused...so I hope someone can help me.

Is the convergence of the Taylor series uniform?

To be more specific. We know for example that

$\displaystyle{ e^x = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^n}{ n!} \quad}$ , $\displaystyle{ \sin x = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{ (-1)^{n+1} }{ (2n+1)!} x^{2n+1} }$

Now the question is: Does these series of functions converges uniformly to $e^x$ and $\sin x$ respectively?

And one more question:
Every Taylor series converges (pointiwise) for every $x$ so has radius of convergence $\infty$ right?

These questions came up when I was studying and saw I my notes that the lecture interchange the summation and the integration of the Taylor series, for example

$\displaystyle{ \frac{1}{ 1+ x^2} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^n x^{2n}, |x|<1 \implies \arctan x = \int_{0}^{x} \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^n t^{2n} dt=  \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^n \int_{0}^{x} t^{2n} dt }$

and I can understand how can we do this if the convergence in not uniform, which in this example is not since $\displaystyle{ \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} x^n = \frac{1}{1-x} }$ pointwise but not uniform.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Hints

For your first question: Weirestrass $\;M$-test;

For your second question: no. For example, the series of $\,\frac1{1-x}\;$ converges only for $\,|x|<1\,$ , and the convergence is uniform for $\,|x|\leq<1\;$ ...

Comment: For the first question I did that and I get that the convergence is uniform on compact intervals is that correct? For the example with the $\arctan x$ how can we interchange the sum and the integral?

Comment: The M-test talks of "sets" on which the conditions are fulfilled, so I think in both first cases you get uniform convergence *everywhere where you can bound* $\,x\,$ . Of course, compact sets are handy here...:) . For the arctangent case you can interchange as long as you can apply the monotone or the domianted convergence theorems...which you can **within** the series's convergence radius.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! It was very helpful!